# How to write a ContainsAll query using LINQ? (C# LINQ-TO-SQL)

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Suppose i have the following

```
var mustHave = new int [] { 1, 2 }
```

and a table named db.Numbers

```
public class Number
{
     public int id;
     public int number;
}
```

populated with

```
Numbers.add(new Number(){id=8,number=1});
Numbers.add(new Number(){id=8,number=2});
Numbers.add(new Number(){id=8,number=3});
Numbers.add(new Number(){id=9,number=1});
Numbers.add(new Number(){id=9,number=3});
```

I want to get all ids which are associated to **all** numbers in the mustHave variable. For example The query must return id=8 but not id=9. The real case is much more complicated and does the query against a database with Linq-To-Sql.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var numbers = Numbers.FindAll(n=>n.id=8);
var mustHave= new int[numbers.Count][2];
int counter = 0;`
foreach(var number in numbers)
{
    mustHave[counter][0]=number.id;
    mustHave[counter][1]=number.number;
    counter++;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am afraid that I need to do it in a single query, without using loops.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you're doing something in LINQtoSQL with a DataContext, try this:

```
var mustHave = new int [] { 1, 2 };
var items = 
  from x in DataContext.SomeTable
  where mustHave.Contains(x.SomeProperty)
  select x;
```

Comment: Your query would return all ids that are associated to at least one of the mustHave array items. What I really want to do is a query that returns the ids that are associated to ALL mustHave array items.